# How to keep some text non-italic in the theorem environment?

Tags: text, italic, renewcommand

I have this preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.3in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{\text{End}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\text{Hom}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
 \End(M_R)
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

My question is: how to keep the commands `\End` and `\Hom` (which create the two words "End" and "Hom") non-italic in the theorem, lemma, corollary, proposition environments ?!. I just need these two words to be non-italic whereas the rest italic as it is.

**Note.** Outside of the aforementioned environments, the words are normal (as it's intended to be).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{\mathrm{End}}` might work?

Comment: Never ever use `\text` for this, it is not what that macro is for. Additionally always write math in math mode, Thus `$\End(M_R)$`

Comment: @Marijn I don't think there is any need to use `\mathrm` in your case it is the default.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn . This is so great.

Comment: @daleif -- But if these are being set in italic within theorems, then their definition should account for that.  So `\mathrm` or `\textup` would fix it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\operatorname` uses `\operator@font`, the same used by `\mathrm`.

Comment: @egreg -- Then the `\text` in th OP's definition is what's causing the problem, and should just be removed.  Oh.  That's already been suggested.  (Afraid I'm a bit scrambled.  Gordon is on the way to the hospital.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `\text`:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
```

Also it should be

```
\begin{lemma}
The endomorphism ring $\End(M_R)$ of the simple module $M_R$ is a division ring.
\end{lemma}
```

Math formulas need to be in math mode. And you should never use `\text` for something inherently math; its purpose is to insert *textual* parts in formulas.